# Delete duplicate pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe

```
ID,col_1,col_2,col_3,PostCode,City,Country
22,Apart 342,The abc,xyz,X01909,London,UK
33,Apt 342,xyz,The abc,X01909,London,UK
41,Apt 342,The abc,xyz,X01909,London,UK
```

Above records are duplicates and one column value is present in other column, I need to delete these duplicates on a very large duplicates.

I have tried `df=df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')`

but it doesn't consider mis spelled data

More Sample

```
ID,col_1,col_2,col_3,PostCode,City,Country
1,Home 25,pearse strret,near spire, 4892,Manchester,UK
2,Pearse,Home no 25,near spire,4892,Manchester,UK
3,Home 25,Pearse street,near spire,4892,Manchester,UK
```

Comment: How do you determine this 3 lines are duplicates? On which criteria?

Comment: `Col_1,Col_2, Col_3 are addresses or landmark - the values of Col_1 are present in Col2, sometimes in Col_3` I want to remove records that are  similar I have add more data for you.

Comment: It would be necessary what exact conditions should be considered as duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas `drop_duplicates` can only perform exact comparisons.
So if you compare `The abc, xyz` and `xyz, The abc` it will see them as non-duplicates. Same goes for capitalization ("the abc" and "The Abc") and misspellings.

The presence of misspelling makes this virtually impossible to solve this perfectly.

If you want to use `drop_duplicates` I would suggest to try and clean the data as much as you can:

- lowercase everything
- create/get a dictionary of abbreviations for your field and expand them (e.g., replace "apt" with "apartment", "no" with "number", ...)
- create a new column, col_4, that somehow combines the data of col_1, col_2 and col_3. This helps in case the information is the same, but switched between columns. (you could concatenate everything, split by word and sort alphabetically...)

After this, you can try and use `df.drop_duplicates(keep="first", subset=<list-of-columns-to-check-for-duplicates>)`.

Of course, it will not mark all duplicates (performance depends on how good you cleaned / normalized the text), but it will help out.

If the dataset is not awfully big, I would suggest to look into fuzzy string matching (https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) and manually compare each pair of samples. You can compare each pair of (cleaned) data, and get a similarity score. You can assume two places are duplicates if the score is close to 100.

Quick and dirty example

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

# without even cleaning the texts
D="Home 25,pearse strret,near spire"
E="Pearse,Home no 25,near spire"
F="Home 25,Pearse street,near spire"

print(fuzz.token_set_ratio(D,E), fuzz.token_set_ratio(D,F), fuzz.token_set_ratio(E,F))
# (94, 97, 94)
# all similarity ratios are over 90: duplicates

A="Apart 342,The abc,xyz"
print(fuzz.token_set_ratio(A,E))
# 24
# similarity score low: not duplicate
```